# Haskell: count an enum (Days of week) by an int

Tags: function, haskell, count, weekday

I want to create a function for a calender programm, that does the following:

```
proceed :: Day -> Int -> Day
> proceed Mon 9
Wed
```

The function proceed should tell me, what weekday it is in 9 days, if today is Monday.

Now I try this:

```
data Day = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun deriving Show

next :: Day -> Day
next Mon = Tue
next Tue = Wed
next Wed = Thu
next Thu = Fri
next Fri = Sat
next Sat = Sun
next Sun = Mon

proceed :: Day -> Int -> Day
proceed d a = if a==0 then next d
              else proceed (next d) (a-1)
```

I try :

```
proceed Mon 9
Thu
```

But that's wrong, the right answear is Wed!!!!!!!
I don't know where I've made the mistake.

Comment: Did you mean `if a == 0 then d else proceed (next d) (a-1)`?  It looks like you just have an off by one error.

Comment: Also, it's really helpful to actually state what your problem is.  This post doesn't have a question in it, I would suggest editing it with more information about what isn't correct about your code.

Comment: I add some more information!

Comment: Is this a different question from this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481043/how-to-write-a-which-day-is-it-after-x-days-recursion-in-haskell

Comment: yeah it is another question! I've only made a off by one error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to bheklilr

```
if a == 0 then d else proceed (next d) (a-1)
```

It was only an off by one error!